# Unexpected gold hammer super powers

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, dupehammer

I just managed to dupe hammer a question with my Delphi gold badge, but the target question does not and never had Delphi tag.

Closed question [Signed executable not showing timestamp and different encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67242950/signed-executable-not-showing-timestamp-and-different-encryption)

Anyone else got gold super powers? Or am I missing something...

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the proposed dupe has that tag, just that the question you're voting to close does.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hate to disappoint, but no superpowers for you, seems like the question *does* have the [delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi) tag:

[image: screenshot of the tag list]

The only requirement for dupe-hammering is that the post *which you are voting to close* has a tag which you have a gold badge in. It doesn't matter what tags the target question has.

From the original [MSE post introducing the dupe hammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212):

> You can instantly close as a duplicate any question that was originally asked with a tag you have a gold badge for.

This doesn't mention any requirement for the target question. The only closure condition is specified in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) page on duplicates (where "generally" refers to the exception of Meta sites):

> The original question generally must have an answer

Comment: That one has, but I thought that original question also needs to have Delphi tag for dupe hammer to work.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar stop, do you mean you thought the *target* has to have one?

Comment: Exactly........

Comment: There is no rule  that the target has to be on the same tag in order to hammer. This is by design, not a bug

Comment: Maybe crop out the user's profile? Showing more of the question is OK, but I'm not sure everyone likes their human profile in screenshots so directly.